# Unstash never finishes in Jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using groovy pipeline in Jenkins. The pipeline steps are something like this:

```
node (label) {
    checkout
    some tests
}

node (label) {
    more tests
    build rpm
    stash rpm
}

node (label) {
    unstash rpm
    install rpm
    do something else
}
```

we did some refactoring of the script and it started behaving in a really weird way. during unstash, the file is copied to the slave fully (size is the same and diff show nothing), but master hangs at this point as if it is still unstash-ing. this also causes high CPU on the master which results in poor performance even after the job is killed.

versions:

- Jenkins: 1.646
- pipeline: 2.2
- groovy: 1.29

EDIT: weirdly, it's not about the size of the file. stashing/unstashing 40M of random bytes works, while 36M of rpm does not.

Comment: Your Jenkins version is very old. There are (should be) no breaking changes in Jenkins 2.0, so better give a more recent version a try.

Comment: i figured out the issue. it had nothing to do with unstash itself, it was https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31484. the caveat is that echo between unstash and the line causing the infinite loop was not printed, probably due to buffering.